# Minimum permission required for obtaining dependency graphs in private repository in github enterprise

Tags: github, graphql, github-enterprise, dependency-graph

I have very little experience in github.
How to give someone permission to view the dependency graph for a repository. I'm not sure if this is possible if the person is not a member or collaborator of the repository. If it's not possible, what is the minimum permission that I can give them that will allow them to view the dependency graph?
Thank you.

I am looking for some kind of api or command as I need to do for a lot of repositories in different org.